# can I use checkbox which is in div with Eventlistener?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
"use strict";

const diaryInput = document.querySelector(".writing");
const titleInput = document.querySelector(".title");
const submitButton = document.querySelector(".dsubmit");
const indexList = document.querySelector(".womb");
const inputTime = document.querySelector(".clock");

const selectAll = document.querySelector(".select");
const unselectAll = document.querySelector(".unselect");
const deleteIndex = document.querySelector(".delete");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", transferDiary);

selectAll.addEventListener("click", selectAllindex);
unselectAll.addEventListener("click", unselectAllindex);
deleteIndex.addEventListener("click", deleteDiaryIndex);

let layout_no = 0;
function transferDiary(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const indexLayout = document.createElement("div");
  indexLayout.classList.add("indexlayout");
  indexLayout.id = "indexlayout-" + layout_no;
  const diaryIndex = document.createElement("div");
  diaryIndex.classList.add("invisible");
  diaryIndex.innerText = diaryInput.value;

  saveLocalDiary(diaryInput.value);

  const diaryTitle = document.createElement("div");
  diaryTitle.classList.add("index");

  const m = new Array(
    "JAN.",
    "FEB.",
    "MAR.",
    "APR.",
    "MAY",
    "JUN.",
    "JUL.",
    "AUG",
    "SEPT.",
    "OCT.",
    "NOV.",
    "DEC."
  );
  const years = date.getFullYear();
  const months = date.getMonth();
  const d = new Array(
    "Sun.",
    "Mon.",
    "Tues.",
    "wed.",
    "Thurs.",
    "Fri.",
    "Sat."
  );
  const days = date.getDay();
  const today = date.getDate();

  diaryTitle.innerHTML = `<input type='checkbox' name='indexchild' value='' class="indexchild" >${m[months]} ${today} ${years} ${d[days]} -${titleInput.value}</>`;

  indexLayout.appendChild(diaryTitle);
  diaryTitle.appendChild(diaryIndex);
  indexList.appendChild(indexLayout);

  const wayBackHome = document.getElementById("indexlayout-" + layout_no);

  wayBackHome.addEventListener("click", bringBackIndex);
  layout_no++;
}

function selectAllindex(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for (const cb of checkboxes) {
    cb.checked = true;
  }
}
function unselectAllindex(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for (const cb of checkboxes) {
    cb.checked = false;
  }
}

function deleteDiaryIndex(i) {
  i.preventDefault();
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      removeDiv(checkboxes[i]);
      removeLocalDiary(checkboxes[i]);
    }
  }
}

function removeDiv(d) {
  console.log(d.parentElement.parentElement);
  console.log(d.parentElement.parentElement[1]);
  d.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}

function bringBackIndex(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const bringEssence = e.target.getElementsByClassName("invisible");
  diaryInput.value = bringEssence[0].innerHTML.replace(
    /\s?(<br\s?\/?>)\s?/g,
    "\r\n"
  );
}

function saveLocalDiary(todo) {
  //check ---- HEy Do I already have thing in localstorage?
  let diary;
  if (localStorage.getItem("diary") === null) {
    diary = [];
  } else {
    diary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("diary"));
  }

  diary.push(todo);
  localStorage.setItem("diary", JSON.stringify(diary));
}

function removeLocalDiary(todo) {
  let diary;
  if (localStorage.getItem("diary") === null) {
    diary = [];
  } else {
    diary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("diary"));
  }
  const todoIndex = todo.children.innerText;
  diary.splice(diary.indexOf(todoIndex), 1);
  localStorage.setItem("diary", JSON.stringify(diary));
}
```

```css
:root {
  --page1-color: #20bf6b;
  --page2-color: #f7b731;
  --page3-color: #4b7bec;
  --text-color: white;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /* 10px=1rem */
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.page3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
 
  background-color: var(--page3-color);
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 600px;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 9px rgb(126, 124, 124),9px 9px 9px rgb(126, 124, 124);
}

.dlayout {
  min-height: 90vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid var(--text-color);
  display: flex;
  

}
.dtitle {
  min-height: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--text-color);
}

.dindex {
  min-width: 10vw;
  max-width: 15vw;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--text-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
}

.diary {
  min-width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  

}
.submit {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--text-color);
}
.submitime {
  padding: 25px 0 0 15px;

  color: var(--text-color);
  min-width: 50%;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.submitarea {
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  min-width: 40%;

  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.title {
  background-color: var(--page3-color);
  border: 1px dashed var(--text-color);
  font-size: 3rem;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;

  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.dsubmit {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: var(--page3-color);
  border: none;
  border-radius:50%;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.dtitle {
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  /* 자간 */
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.writing {
  background-color: var(--page3-color);
  border: none;
  height: 90%;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: var(--text-color);
  opacity: 0.5;
  
}
textarea{
  resize: none;
}
.indexlayout {
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid var(--text-color);
  margin:5px;
  
  
}

.invisible {
  display:none ;
}
.womb{
  overflow: scroll;
}
.selector{
  color: var(--text-color);
  width: 100%;
  border:none;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--text-color);
  min-height: 5%;
  background-color: var(--page3-color);
  outline: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-weight: 300;
  
}

.index{
  word-break: break-all;
   
}

.indexchild{

}
.selector:hover{
  color:var(--page3-color);
  background-color: var(--text-color);

}

.dsubmit:hover{
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 3px rgb(172, 172, 172), 3px 3px 3px rgb(237, 237, 237),;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.indexlayout:hover{
  color:var(--page3-color);
  background-color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<section class="page3">
<div class="dlayout">
  <form id="indexo" name="indexi" class="dindex">
    <div class="dtitle"><p>Diary</p></div>
    <div class="womb"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="selector select" value="selectall">Select All</button>
      <button class="selector unselect" value="unselectall">Unselect All</button>
      <button class="selector delete" value="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
    
  </form>
  <div class="diary">
    <div class="submit">
    <div class="submitime clock"></div>
    <form class="submitarea">
      Title:    <input type="text" class="title" />
      <button class="dsubmit"><img src="./arrow-circle-right-solid.svg" alt=""></button>
      
    </form>
  </div>
    <textarea  class="writing" placeholder="  shit something..."></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Hello, I am struggling code above. It is a quite simple diary, the right side has a textarea
tag so you can write your diary and also has a transfer button so you push it, left side is gonna have an index of what you wrote. and I also added a checkbox on the index so you can select/unselect/delete them all at once. if perfectly works fine until I added another function. I added Eventlistener(handler is click) on the index(div .indexlayout), when you click the index it is gonna bring back what you wrote into the textarea tag.

```
  const wayBackHome = document.getElementById("indexlayout-" + layout_no);

  wayBackHome.addEventListener("click", bringBackIndex);
```

It works also okay. so I was quite satisfied. However, a little while later, I found that checkboxes don't work ever since added a new function!!
to be specific, select/unselect All buttons still work and I can check checkboxes with those, but I cannot select checkboxes individually :/
I think it is because I added an event on div which is a parent of a checkbox.
But, not gonna lie, I had no idea how to solve this. I tried "wayBackHome.innerText" or even added event to other div but it didn't work. Could you tell me what I missed and How do I fix it please?
thx!

Comment: I do not see any checkbox in your code. Can you add an example of the elements queried using `"indexlayout-" + layout_no` please.

Comment: yea if i create i index with button it would be like this

Comment: <div class="inexlayout" id="indexlayout-0">
     <div class="index">
       <input type="checkbox" name="indexchild" class="indexchild">
       "JUL. 6 2021 Tues. -"
       <div class="invisible"></div>
     </div>
   </div>

Comment: I can not reproduce the bug. The checkox is still selectable on my tests. Can you add your `bringBackIndex` function ? Doesn't it contains a `event.preventDefault()` call ?

Comment: OMG yes you are right it has event.preventDefault and I removed it and it works well now! but I still don't understand why preventDefalut prevent checkboxes can you tell me why?

Comment: and appreciate for your help!!

Comment: `preventDefault`, as its name indicate, prevent the default comportment of your element, that is to be checked/unchecked on click

Comment: [Here is the MDN reference about Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), there even is an example about checkboxes